# Delete a Managed Object using Tooling or Metadata API when Deletable

Tags: managed-package, metadata-api, tooling-api

Trying to delete a validation rule in subscriber org using either the tooling or metadata API

This validation rule WAS part of a managed package but was deleted from the package and new version installed.

The validation rule CAN be deleted via the UI by clicking **Del** next to the validation rule.

All attempts at deleting the rule using the API's result in the error

> Cannot modify managed object: entity=ValidationFormula, component=03d1I000000EgZx, field=ValidationFormula, state=installed

Has anyone been able to do this via the Tooling or Metadata API?

Is this something that can only be done via the UI?

To be clear code works sans this specific use case. Just trying to figure out if it is possible to do and if so what needs to be sent in the payload other than the standard `deleteMetadata` payload